# Pass query from Link to server, first time load query value undefined, after reload get correct query

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, next.js

I try to create some API to external adobe stock.
Like in the title, first time i get query from Link router of undefined, but after reload page it work correctly. My 
main page

```js
<Link 
  href={{
    pathname: "/kategoria-zdjec", 
    query: images.zdjecia_kategoria
  }}
  as={`/kategoria-zdjec?temat=${images.zdjecia_kategoria}`}
  className={classes.button}>
</Link>
```

and my server

```js
app
 .prepare()
 .then(() => {
   server.get("/kategoria-zdjec", async (req, res) => {
     const temat = await req.query.temat;
     console.log(temat)
     const url = `https://stock.adobe.io/Rest/Media/1/Search/Files?locale=pl_PL&search_parameters[words]=${temat}&search_parameters[limit]=24&search_parameters[offset]=1`;
      try {
        const fetchData = await fetch(url, {
          headers: { ... }
         });
         const objectAdobeStock = await fetchData.json();
         res.json(objectAdobeStock);
         const totalObj = await objectAdobeStock.nb_results;
         const adobeImages = await objectAdobeStock.files;
      } catch (error) {
         console.log(error);
      }
  });
```

and that looks like `getInitialProps` on page next page

```js
    Zdjecia.getInitialProps = async ({req}) => {
      const res = await fetch("/kategoria-zdjec");
      const json = await res.json();
      return { total: json.nb_results, images: json.files };
    }
```

I think it is problem due asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be due to the fact that you are using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) which is actually part of the Web API and this action fails when executed on server.

You could either use [isomorphic-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch) which keeps fetch API consistent between client and server, or use [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) when fetch is called on the server:

```js
Zdjecia.getInitialProps = async ({ req, isServer }) => {
  const fetch = isServer ? require('node-fetch') : window.fetch;
  const res = await fetch("/kategoria-zdjec");
  const json = await res.json();
  return { total: json.nb_results, images: json.files };
}
```

Comment: on server I use node-fetch, also inside in getInitialProps i use fetch from isomorphic-fetch library. I apply ternary witch you advice me, and this is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved, the issue was in another part of my app, directly in state management, just created new variables, and pass to link state value.